SP2019 & jQuery: On Choice Selection, Concatenate Date + Choice-made + Modified By, Send to Mult Lines of Text Field
One of the most frequent questions I get on a SP2019 Classic List is "what, when, who":
What Choice option was selected, by whom, and when?
Using [MyChoice] choice field and [MyMultiLines] multiple lines of text field, can you suggest a jQuery script to paste the following into a Multiple Lines of Text field?
12/1/2024 1:20 PM - Blue Choice - John.User@company.com

You can achieve this using jQuery by capturing these details in Add/Edit form and set value in your field before the save operation. But it has one glitch that if someone updates the choice field from quick edit, it will not able to capture that change.
Note:

Please add below script in the script editor web part in list add and edit forms to capture this.
I have taken fields for the example. You can update as per your logic.

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var userEmail = '';
    
            // Function to get the current user's email using AJAX
        function getCurrentUserEmail() {
            $.ajax({
                url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/currentuser",
                type: "GET",
                headers: {
                    "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    userEmail = data.d.Email;
                    updateNotesField();
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
                }
            });
        }
    
            // Function to get the current date and time
            function getCurrentDateTime() {
                var now = new Date();
                return now.toLocaleString();
            }
    
            // Function to update the Notes field
            function updateNotesField() {
                var status = $("select[title='Status']").val();
                var dateTime = getCurrentDateTime();
                var notes = status + " - " + dateTime + " - " + userEmail;
                $("textarea[title='Notes']").val(notes);
            }
    
            // Attach change event to the Status field
            $("select[title='Status']").change(function() {
                updateNotesField();
            });
    
            // Initial call to get the current user's email and set the Notes field if Status is already selected
            getCurrentUserEmail();
        });
    </script>

Output:


Best Approach: List Event receiver
The best way to achieve this to use List Event receivers. It will trigger each time when someone updates the item from anywhere. In this, you can write your logic to update your multiline text column.
Here, is one nice reference for list item add/update event receiver example: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/5b1f04/create-a-custom-list-level-event-receiver-for-item-updated-i/

Hi Dikesh:  I tried the first approach using jQuery in the New and Edit forms but it's not working.  I added it as you displayed it and then added "" above it, but neither worked. I verified the [Status] and [Notes] names as well.
If I can get Visual Studio, I will try your "best approach."
If you have any ideas why this is not working in Chrome, let me know. Thanks!

Updated: I do not have rights to add a VS created project to the farm collection.

@ChasEpes: I have updated my script to apply in add/edit forms. Please update column names as per your need in the script. Also, for your chrome browser, check for any error in the browser developer tool and add in your question to troubleshoot further.
